# Karma not recognizing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using Jasmine testing with Phantomjs and Karma.

I'm getting an error as soon as karma reaches jquery in my included script.

I have it included in my `files: []` section however.

Here's what my `karma.config.js` file looks like

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',


    frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery','jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

       'resources/assets/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
       'resources/assets/bower/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',

      // I tried loading them in with a CDN also
       //"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js",
      //"https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js",

      'public/js/vendor.js',
      'spec/mainjsTests/*.js',
      'spec/javascripts/fixtures/*.css',

      // fixtures
  {
    pattern: 'spec/javascripts/fixtures/*.html',
    watched: true,
    included: true,
    served: true
  }
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins: [
              'karma-*'
             ],

    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

All my JS files get built into the vendor file so I just linked that one. They're listed in the order they're called from my Gulp file.

As soon as Karma reaches the first line of jQuery it errors out.

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.36 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket sHWba0Xi_dR9PuTbDdhx with id 19415635
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('uploadFile').files')
  at /Users/me/PersonalProjects/HSAnnotator/public/js/vendor.js:2975
```

I tested this by commenting out this line, and it then errors out at the next line of jQuery.

Everything besides jQuery is installed with npm, only jquery is installed with bower. I don't think this should matter since I also tried with a CDN link which leads me to believe I have something else in my `karma.config` file listed wrong.

Comment: This doesn't look like it's an issue with jquery, but rather with what some library is trying to do. It seems like this is being caused by `document.getElementById('uploadFile')` returning `null`. Can you post your specs?

Comment: Here's the code snippet it's referring to :
 
`/**
*** Check if a file has been loaded.
*** If no file then display a message to load one
**/
if (document.getElementById('uploadFile').files[0] == null) {
  $('.fileName').html('Please Load a File to Begin');
};`

Comment: I have the same situation with the same outcome